# spark ml pipeline - 2 classes in labeled field but spark cant run binomial regression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

i validated that the label field has only 2 possible values by running select distinct on it.
but spark gives an error that it can't assign binomial family in logistic regression for 3 classes in label field

Comment: Can you please provide more details ? Especially a `df.groupBy('label').count()` You may have remaining null values.

Comment: i verified there are no nulls.

    df.select("observations").distinct().show(5) gave only [0,1]
to be sure i also replaced nulls before with 0 by :
df.withColumn("observations", when(df.observations.isin([0,1])==False,0).otherwise(df.observations))